# Cisco Packet Tracer - OSPF network variable length subnet

Tags: ospf, packet-tracer

I'm not sure if I going crazy or not. I try to configure an ospf network:

```
(conf)#router ospf 1
      #network 10.73.90.80 0.0.0.63 area 0
```

I then type `show running` and it reverts to `10.73.90.64 0.0.0.63` address. I have no clue on why this is happening. I've also tried it on a new file and on a router that is isolated.

It's probably definitely something silly I've missed...

Answer (score 4):

The address 10.73.90.80/26 is a host address, not a correct network address.

The network address (given that mask) is 10.75.90.64, which is what the router converts it to.